# How to search class deserialized from xml for specific value, and place nodes into it

Tags: c#, .net, xml, class, serialization

I have an xml document that was build from classes then serialized. Later, I have deserialized the data and have used the same class structure. I currently have a variable that is filled with objects. What I need now, is the ability to search each object for a specific value, if the value exists, append new data as a child. I have poked around with Reflection and the GetValue property in .NET but have become rather confused. Some sample code is below.

Thank you.

```
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement("Product")]
    public List<Product> Product { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Modification")]
    public List<Modification> Modification { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public List<ColorVariants> ColorVariants { get; set;}
    public List<FeatureAddOns> FeatureAddOns { get; set; }
}

DataTable DTFeatureAddOn = new DataTable();
DTFeatureAddOn.Columns.Add("ProductID", typeof(String));
DTFeatureAddOn.Columns.Add("ProductName", typeof(String));

DataRow drDTFeatureAddOn = DTFeatureAddOn.NewRow();
drDTFeatureAddOn["ProductID"] = "ProductID";
drDTFeatureAddOn["ProductName"] = "ProductName";

DTFeatureAddOn.Rows.Add(drDTFeatureAddOn);

catalogFeed = DeserializeCatalogFeed();

if (DTFeatureAddOn.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in DTFeatureAddOn.Rows)
{
//a. For each unique ProductID, first check to make sure the does not exist – if NOT then create
    List<int> ProductIDList = new List<int>();
    PropertyInformation pinfo = typeof(Root).GetProperty("ProductID");
    //foreach (catalogFeed.Product
    //b. For each PlacementCode, create a structure FeatureAddOn below that ProductID.  This may results into a list of FeatureAddons for a given ProductID
    }


SerializeToXML(catalogFeed, DeltaCatalogFeedUpload.FileName);
}

    public static void SerializeToXML(Root rootNode, string FileName)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(FileName);
        serializer.Serialize(tw, rootNode);
        tw.Close();
    }

    public static Root DeserializeFromXML()
    {
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
        TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(DeltaCatalogFeedUpload.FileName);
        Root nodes;
        nodes = (Root)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
        textReader.Close();

        return nodes;
    }

    public static Root DeserializeCatalogFeed()
    {
        Root root = new Root();
        try
        {

            FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(DeltaCatalogFeedUpload.FileName);
            if (fInfo.Exists)
            {

                root = DeserializeFromXML();

            }
            else
            {
                root.Product = new List<Product>();
                root.Modification = new List<Modification>();
                root.PlacementCodeList = new List<PlacementCodeList>();
                root.AssociatedSKU = new List<AssociatedSKU>();
                root.FontStyle = new List<FontStyle>();
                root.FontSize = new List<FontSize>();
                root.FontType = new List<FontType>();
                root.Alignment = new List<Alignment>();
                root.ThreadColor = new List<ThreadColor>();                    
                root.Category = new List<Category>();
                root.ProductLine = new List<ProductLine>();
                root.ProductStock = new List<ProductStock>();
                root.ProductFiber = new List<ProductFiber>();                    
                root.ProductFabric = new List<ProductFabric>();
                root.Season = new List<Season>();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // do something with the error but always return a price list
            root.Product = new List<Product>();
            root.Modification = new List<Modification>();
            root.PlacementCodeList = new List<PlacementCodeList>();
            root.AssociatedSKU = new List<AssociatedSKU>();
            root.FontStyle = new List<FontStyle>();
            root.FontSize = new List<FontSize>();
            root.FontType = new List<FontType>();
            root.Alignment = new List<Alignment>();
            root.ThreadColor = new List<ThreadColor>();
            root.Category = new List<Category>();
            root.ProductLine = new List<ProductLine>();
            root.ProductStock = new List<ProductStock>();
            root.ProductFiber = new List<ProductFiber>();
            root.ProductFabric = new List<ProductFabric>();
            root.Season = new List<Season>();
        }
        return root;
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of `catalogFeed`? Your question doesn't say anything about the use of a `DataTable`, so your code doesn't seem to match the question. Could you show the code you're using to deserialize the xml?

Comment: I have added the code for the serialize and deserialize functions. The DataTable contains incoming data that I need to add to the XML. I apologize if I am not being clear. Basically, I want to get ID's from the DataTable, Check "catalogFeed" for the ID's. If they are there, Add the new data as nodes of FeatureAddOns in Product.

Comment: That helps. I'll post an answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for [LINQ to Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx).

`catalogFeed.Product` is a list of `Product` objects (`List<Product>`). Personally, I would have named that property `Products`, but that would just be for readability.

Assuming from your code that `Product` class has a property named `ProductID` and that is what you want to match on.

I would create a dictionary of `Product` objects with `ProductID` as the key. Do this via the [`ToDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRARY/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx) LINQ method like this:

```
var productLookup = catalogFeed.Product.ToDictionary(p => p.ProductID);
```

Then inside your loop through the data table, you can locate the matching product in the dictionary.

```
foreach (DataRow row in DTFeatureAddOn.Rows)
{
    var productId = row["ProductID"];
    if (productLookup.ContainsKey(productId))
    {
        var matchingProduct = productLookup[productId];
        // get whatever you need out of the matching product.
    }
}
```

You could use a LINQ query to locate the matching product on each iteration through the loop, but using the `ToDictionary` approach means that the scan of the list only happens once. It's essentially creating an in-memory index so you can quickly find the object you're looking for without scanning the whole list each time, but if you did want to do that, finding a single matching product by `ProductID` with [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549039(v=vs.110).aspx) would look like this:

```
var matchingProduct = catalogFeed.Product.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID = desiredProductID);
```

If there was no match, then `matchingProduct` would be `null`.

Comment: That was rather helpful thank you. I am getting the error "An item with the same key has already been added." when I try running ToDictionary. Assuming I get that to work, would I be able to add nodes that already exist using this method? I can kind of see how I would, inside your if statement, append a new instance of the list to the node?

Comment: Oh, ToDictionary assumes that the Key is unique. Do you have duplicate ProductIDs? i.e. more than one `Product` in the list with the same `ProductID`? Maybe you could add a bit more info to your question regarding the shape of your data.

Comment: In some cases, the ID's will be the same yes. Sadly, I do not have control over the incoming XML that I am adding to. I was able to get something similar to your second example to work "catalogFeed.Product.Exists(x => x.ProductID == row["ProductID"].ToString())" It returns a bool that I can use to decide if I am adding a new node or adding a child node. I am still fighting with how I would add that child node however.